# Regular surfaces with $z=0$

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization

I have the problems 2.2 and 2.9 of *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces* by Manfredo do Carmo and this problems give me a doubt. They are:

> Is the set $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3;z=0\qquad x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ a regular surface? Is the set $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3;z=0\qquad x^2+y^2< 1\}$ a regular surface?

and

> Let $V$ be an open set of plane $xy$. Show that:
>   $$\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3;z=0\qquad (x,y)\in V\}$$
>   is a regular surface.

Well, I thinked as follow:

Given any $V\in \mathbb{R^3}$ (open or not), there is $V^*\supset V$ open in $\mathbb{R^3}$. Consider $f(u,v)=(u,v,0)$ from $V^*$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

This is a differenciable function, an homeomorphism, and its derivative is injective, so I thinked that this proves that any set of form
$$\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3;z=0\qquad (x,y)\in V\}$$

is a regular surface.

By the questions above, I think I am wrong, but I could not understand yet.

Thanks in advance for a help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix an open subset $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, then indeed for every $k \in \mathbb{R}$
$$\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: z = k, (x,y) \in V\}$$
is a regular surface parametrized by $\phi: V \to \mathbb{R}^3$, $\phi(x,y) = (x,y,0)$. The open hypothesis can't be removed: for example, your set
$$\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: z = 0, x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$$ is not a regular surface. For example, you won't find a neighbourhood of any point on the border that is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, I think I understood what you mean. The book considers for each neighborhood $V$ of $p\in S$ an application $f:U(open)\rightarrow V\cap S$ s.t. is differenciable, homeomorphism and has injective derivative. For instance, why I do not consider $U=x^2+y^2<2$ for the second set? Because $V\cap S$ does not contain the dominium of $f$, so I cannot restrict the function to this dominium?

Comment: Be careful: $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, while domain of $f$ should be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. You can use larger open subsets as domain, if you don't require your function to be bijective (in particular, not surjective).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I would like to write codomain instead of domain. Many thanks.